# Junit test is throwing Error when i try to run it using ant build script

Tags: java, ant, junit

Junit is Throwing ClassNotFound Exception when i try to run using ant build script. stuck!!

Class file is there in the folder and libs are referenced properly.

My Script:

```
<target name="run-junit-test" >
        <mkdir dir="testReports" />
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" />
                <pathelement location="src/tests" />
                <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/junit-4.11.jar" />
                <pathelement location="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar" />
                <pathelement location="/opt/jdk1.6.0_35/jre/lib" />
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="plain" />
            <formatter type="xml" />

            <batchtest fork="yes" todir="testReports">
                <fileset dir="src/tests">
                    <include name="**/*Test*.java" />
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
```

Error I am Getting :

```
Testsuite: TestJunit
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec

    Caused an ERROR
TestJunit
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestJunit
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
```

Comment: Are your `TestJunit` clas in the default package? Generally that's not suggested because you cannot refer to that class. I'd advise putting it into a single package.